# How to get more search results than the server's sizelimit with Python LDAP?

Tags: python, ldap

I am using the [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/) module to (amongst other things) search for groups, and am running into the server's size limit and getting a `SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` exception.  I have tried both synchronous and asynchronous searches and hit the problem both ways.

You are supposed to be able to work round this by setting a paging control on the search, but according to the python-ldap docs these controls are not yet implemented for `search_ext()`.  Is there a way to do this in Python? If the `python-ldap` library does not support it, is there another Python library that does?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. I need to process more results than the size limit, using python.

Comment: In a pinch, binding to the LDAP server with root dn credentials - as opposed to the default anonymous bind - will circumvent the SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED restriction.  However, paged results (or pagination) - as outlined below - is the way to go from both a client and server perspective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some links related to paging in python-ldap.

- Documentation: http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap-controls.html#ldap.controls.SimplePagedResultsControl
- Example code using paging: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/18274.html
- More example code: http://google-apps-for-your-domain-ldap-sync.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ldap_ctxt.py

Comment: Those examples are outdated. I'm using Python 2.6 and 2.7 with python-ldap >= 2.3.11 and the syntax has changed a bit. See https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/python-ldap/src/f208b6338a28/Demo/paged_search_ext_s.py for an up to date example.

Comment: Thinks one works for Python 3.  Kudos to RIAAN!  https://blog.ls-al.com/python-ldap-query-active-directory/

Comment: This also ran for me for Python 3. https://gist.github.com/mattfahrner/c228ead9c516fc322d3a written by mattfahrner

Comment: Also in official python-ldap github page, Demo directory, there is [paged_search_ext_s.py](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/main/Demo/paged_search_ext_s.py), worked perfectly

Answer (score 8):

After some discussion on the python-ldap-dev mailing list, I can answer my own question.

Page controls ARE supported by the Python lDAP module, but the docs had not been updated for search_ext to show that.  The [example linked by Gorgapor](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/18274.html) shows how to use the ldap.controls.SimplePagedResultsControl to read the results in pages.

However there is a gotcha.  This will work with Microsoft Active Directory servers, but not with OpenLDAP servers (and possibly others, such as Sun's).  The [LDAP controls RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2696.txt) is ambiguous as to whether paged controls should be allowed to override the server's sizelimit setting.  On ActiveDirectory servers they can by default while on OpenLDAP they cannot, but I think there is a server setting that will allow them to.

So even if you implement the paged control, there is still no guarantee that it will get all the objects that you want. *Sigh*

Also paged controls are only available with LDAP v3, but I doubt that there are many v2 servers in use.

Comment: The python-based ldap browser, Luma, seems to be working around this limitation somehow. I've been trying to look through its source code to figure it out, but have had no luck. Also, Could you link to the python-ldap-dev thread you mentioned?

Comment: Client-requested resource limits such as time limit and size limit can never override the servers' resource limits. To determine which request controls are supported, query the root DSE(http://bit.ly/the-root-dse).