# LDAP: ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: python, ldap

I am getting an `ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` error when I run this code:

```
import ldap

url = 'ldap://<domain>:389'
binddn = 'cn=<username> readonly,cn=users,dc=tnc,dc=org'
password = '<password>'

conn = ldap.initialize(url)
conn.simple_bind_s(binddn,password)

base_dn = "ou=People,dc=tnc,dc=org"
filter = '(objectClass=*)'
attrs = ['sn']

conn.search_s( base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs )
```

Where `username` is my actual username, `password` is my actual password, and `domain` is the actual domain.

I don't understand why this is. Can somebody shed some light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manual: http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html

> *exception* `ldap`.**`SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED`**
>   An LDAP size limit was exceeded. This
>   could be due to a `sizelimit`
>   configuration on the LDAP server.

I think your best bet here is to limit the `sizelimit` on the message you receive from the server. You can do that by setting the attribute `LDAPObject.sizelimit` (deprecated) or using the sizelimit parameter when using `search_ext()`

You should also make sure your bind was actually successful...

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess that should have been my first source.

Comment: It should be noted that while you can use `search_ext(size=desired_num)` to avoid the `ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` exception, this won't let you view all of the users. The sizelimit doesn't overwrite the server's settings so if the server has the sizelimit set to 100 users you can't just set the size to 500 and expect to get them all back.

Answer (score 6):

You're encountering that exception most likely because the server you're communicating with has more results than can be returned by a single request. In order to get around this you need to use paged results which can be done by using [SimplePagedResultsControl](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-controls.html).

Here's a Python3 implementation that I came up with after heavily editing what I found [here](https://blog.ls-al.com/python-ldap-query-active-directory/) and in the [official documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html). At the time of writing this it works with the pip3 package [python-ldap](https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/) version 3.2.0.

```
def get_list_of_ldap_users():
    hostname = "<domain>:389"
    username = "username_here"
    password = "password_here"
    base = "ou=People,dc=tnc,dc=org"

    print(f"Connecting to the LDAP server at '{hostname}'...")
    connect = ldap.initialize(f"ldap://{hostname}")
    connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    connect.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    search_flt = "(objectClass=*)"
    page_size = 500 # how many users to search for in each page, this depends on the server maximum setting (default highest value is 1000)
    searchreq_attrlist=["sn"] # change these to the attributes you care about
    req_ctrl = SimplePagedResultsControl(criticality=True, size=page_size, cookie='')
    msgid = connect.search_ext(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])

    total_results = []
    pages = 0
    while True: # loop over all of the pages using the same cookie, otherwise the search will fail
        pages += 1
        rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = connect.result3(msgid)
        for user in rdata:
            total_results.append(user)

        pctrls = [c for c in serverctrls if c.controlType == SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType]
        if pctrls:
            if pctrls[0].cookie: # Copy cookie from response control to request control
                req_ctrl.cookie = pctrls[0].cookie
                msgid = connect.search_ext(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
    return total_results
```

This will return a list of all users but you can edit it as required to return what you want without hitting the `SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` issue :)

Comment: Also in official python-ldap github page, Demo directory, there is a similar solution in
[paged_search_ext_s.py](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/main/Demo/paged_search_ext_s.py), worked lovely for me also with active directory

Answer (score 2):

see here for what to do when you get this error:

[How get get more search results than the server's sizelimit with Python LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073574/how-get-get-more-search-results-than-the-servers-sizelimit-with-python-ldap/2086982#2086982)

Answer (score 2):

The filter you provided (`objectClass=*`) is a *presence filter*. In this case it limits the results to the search request to objects in the directory at and underneath the base object you supplied - which is every object underneath the base object since every object has at least one `objectClass`. Restrict your search by using a more restrictive filter, or a tighter scope, or a lower base object, or all three. For more information on the topic of the search request, see *[Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)* and [*LDAP: Programming Practices*](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/).

Directory Server administrators are free to impose a server-wide limit on entries that can be returned to LDAP clients, these are known as a *server-imposed* size limit. There is a time limit which follows the same rules.

LDAP clients should always supply a size limit and time limit with a search request, these limits, known as *client-requested limits* cannot override the server-imposed limits, however.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory defaults to returning a max of 1000 results.  What is sort of annoying is that rather than return 1000, with an associated error code, it seems to send the error code without the data.

eDirectory starts with no default, and is completely conifgurable to whatever you like.

Other directories handle it differently.  (Edit and add in, if you know).

Comment: I figured that that was happening. So, what I do now is return query by first letter of last name. This is a better idea than showing thousands of employees at one time.

Comment: Be aware that searching by first letter of a name does not work.  Since eventually your data set will get large enough to return more than 1000 S's and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You must use paged search to achieve this.
The page size would depend on your ldap server, 1000 would work for Active Directory.

Have a look at http://google-apps-for-your-domain-ldap-sync.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ldap_ctxt.py for an example